# Can I fetch service PID using Saltstack?

Tags: salt-stack

How can I get the service PID like tomcat or jboss?
I used [salt.modules.service](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.service.html#module-salt.modules.service) to start/stop service, but it seems I can not get the PID of the service.

Answer (score 2):

You execute arbitrary shell commands in salt, which could be used to retrieve a process' PID:

```
salt minion-name cmd.run 'pgrep tomcat'
```

You can also use this pattern in a salt state, templating it up with jinja. For example:

```
linux-headers:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: linux-headers-{{ salt['cmd.run']('uname -r') }}
```